# DestinationCidrBlock property of AWS::EC2::Route

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-cloudformation

I went through a tutorial and it has 
    "DestinationCidrBlock" : "0.0.0.0/0", 
What exactly this mean. Does it always have this ip address. If not how should I decide the value of this properties. Any information would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

A CIDR range of `0.0.0.0/0` refers to the entire Internet.

This is typically used for an **Inbound rule**, effectively saying that anybody (*the entire Internet*) is permitted inbound access on a particular port.

It is also possible to used a more restrictive address, such as a `/32` range which refers to **one IP address only** (eg `54.11.22.33/32`), or anything between `/0` and `/32`. Calculating ranges can be difficult, so an online [CIDR calculator](https://www.google.com/search?q=cidr+calculator) can be used.

See: [Classless Inter-Domain Routing - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing)

Comment: So, it refers the IP addresses in the internet through which access is possible and we can assign the range of IP addresses that can access the resources?

Comment: Yes. An _Inbound Rule_ controls which IP addresses are allowed to access the protected resource and an _Outbound Rule_ controls which resources can be accessed _from_ the resource.